# Enquote title using csquotes

Tags: titles, punctuation, csquotes

I use the package `csquotes` and the `\enquote` command to place quotes in my documents that depend on my babel settings. For my current document I would like to enquote of an article. Therefore I wrote `\title{\enquote{...}}`. Unfortunately, I have the term `I'd` in my title. When I use British english for my document the quotes look similar to the half quote in `I'd`. Is there a possibility to change that behaviour?

**Update**

The whole command is `\title{\enquote*{I never did say how, but I told you I'd get you out of Vietnam}}`.

Comment: Next time it would be better if you create an answer to an answer like this so I can accept your answer and mark the question as solved... Just an advice.

Comment: I wanted to use this quotes to make clear that this title is a quote (the title of a cartoon I interpreted). The task is mentioned in the subtitle.

Comment: Well, that makes sense!  (Not thinking clearly today...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest `csquotes`-based solution is to use `\enquote*{<text>}`, which switches the quotation marks from the outer to the inner style.  Thus you get "double" instead of 'single' quotation marks when you have `british` English as the default document language via `babel`.  (With `\usepackage[american]{babel}`, you'd get 'single' rather than "double" using `\enquote*{<text>}`.)

Another possibility, is to use `\textquotesingle` from the `textcomp` package.  Probably won't look very nice, but it is a possibility if you want to distinguish between the closing single quotation mark and the apostrophe....